# how do I test code agenst `catkin install`-ed directory

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I understand correctly `catkin_make test` uses code under `devel` directory, is there way to test code for `install` directory?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131646/how-do-i-test-code-agenst-%60catkin-install%60-ed-directory/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-04-01**:
Can you clarify a little bit?  There's no catkin_test command.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-04-01**:
sorry, I asked about `catkin_make test` against installed program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All tests are only run against the devel space. So you can not run the unit tests of a specific package against the installed version of the same package.

What you can do is run the tests of a package `foo` against the installed version of all dependencies. Therefore you first build and install all dependencies using one workspace and then use a second workspace containing `foo` and run its tests. Usually those kind of tests are not unit tests but integration tests - you might consider to bundle integration tests into separate packages (which you could ignore when releasing a repo) for this purpose.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0